# Apex Controller get request Body

Tags: apex

I have an apex controller tied to an apex Visualforce page, I know how to get the parameters on the request by using:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
```

but how can I get the body of that request, for example if a JSON is sent through the body how can I receive it and parse it in my controller.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a specific Apex method in the class for handling REST requests.

E.g.

```
@HttpGet
global static Account doGet() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    String accountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    Account result = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
    return result;
}
```

In particular, the [RestRequest.requestBody](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm#apex_System_RestRequest_requestBody).

See:

- [RestRequest Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm)
- [RestContext Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_restcontext.htm)
- [Apex REST Methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_methods.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to see what data is in the GET request body sent to Salesforce to render your Visualforce page.  In other words, if your VF page is called `MyPage` then when you send a GET to `https://na1.salesforce.com/apex/MyPage` you want `MyPage`'s Controller to be able to see the body of that GET request?

If that's the actual question, I don't think you can.  Daniel's answer applies to Apex ReST services which would be a much better solution to your issue.  Generally a GET request should not have a body.